# reshape R data frame long to wide

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape, data-manipulation

I'm trying to reshape my data from long to wide

```
set.seed(1)
y <- rnorm(12, 0, 1)
x <- rep(c("A","B"), each=6)
g <- rep(c("g1", "g2"), each=3)
t <-  rep(c(1,2,3), times=4)
df <- data.frame(y=y, x=x, g=g, t=t)
```

This is what I'm hoping to get:

```
    A.1     A.2     A.3    B.1     B.2     B.3
g1  -0.626  0.183  -0.835  0.487   0.738   0.575
g2  1.595   0.329  -0.820  -0.305  1.511   0.389
```

I tried with `reshape`

```
reshape(df, idvar = "g", timevar = "t", direction = "wide")
```

but I don't know how to add `x` to the columns

Comment: Can you explain how you obtained the first element 0.322?

Comment: Could you include `set.seed` to make the question reproducible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `pivot_wider`. Also, I added a more compact form of your toy data set using `expand.grid`.

```
library(tidyr)

df <- data.frame(y=y, expand.grid(t=c(1,2,3), g=c("g1", "g2"), x=c("A","B")))
pivot_wider(df, values_from = y, names_from = c(x,t), names_sep = ".")

  g        A.1   A.2    A.3    B.1   B.2   B.3
  <fct>  <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 g1    -0.626 0.184 -0.836  0.487 0.738 0.576
2 g2     1.60  0.330 -0.820 -0.305 1.51  0.390
```